# Typo in election page "candidiates"

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

There's a typo in the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14), where it reads:

> Primary (active only if there are >10 candid**i**ates)

it should be *candidates*.

Comment: Indeed it should.  Fixed.